# How do I update a 'List<Map>' with BLoC and equatable?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am still a beginner with BLoC architecture. So far the UI updates when using `int`, `bool`, and other basic data types. But when it comes to Lists and Maps it really confuses me. My code basically looks like this:

```
// STATE CLASS
class MyBlocState extends Equatable {
  final List someData;
  
  const MyBlocState({required this.someData});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [someData];

  // I tried doing this too. Not sure if it's correct. It didn't work anyway!
  List<Object> get props => [...someData];
}


// INITIAL STATE CLASS
  class MyBlocInitial extends MyBlocState {
    MyBlocInitial() : super(someData: [{"a": "unknown", "bool": false}, {"b": "unknown", "bool": false}]);
  }


// EVENT CLASS
  ...
  ...


// BLOC CLASS
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyBlocEvent, MyBlocState> {
  MyBloc() : super(MyBlocInitial()) {
    on<UpdateSomeDataEvent>((event, emit) {
      var newData = [{"a": "Apple", "bool": true}, {"b": "Blue", "bool": true}]
      emit(MyBlocState(someData: newData));
    });
  }
}
```

I tried creating new instances, using `List.from`, `Map.from`, emptying the array and filling it again, and I just ended up complicating the code without any effects. I know it's something concerning 'Equatable', comparing previous and new states, but I have no clue on how to work around it. Any extra information related to this will be deeply appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code as posted here - Can you show how you're using the Bloc?

Comment: Although it might have to do with the fact that the List in MyBlocState is implicitly declared as List<dynamic>. Perhaps you can see what happens if you declare it as List<Map<String, dynamic>>?

Comment: @MichaelHorn Thanks for reaching out. I tried to do so but no changes. I've actually modified the code to use models instead of Maps but it's the same problem still.

Comment: I think it's related on how you used the bloc. Can you share the widget code where you used it? And definitely remove the "List<Object> get props => [...someData];" - that makes no sense and will never be triggered in your code anyways.